# Stub generated using Axis2 is unable to Maintain session between RESTful service and Client

Tags: session, rest, apache-axis

I created a webservice and enabled session management on both server and client. It works FINE until I enable REST on the client by adding the 3rd line of code in the serviceStub.java.
The session management stops working.

```
// session management 
_serviceClient.getOptions().setManageSession(true); 
_serviceClient.engageModule("addressing");

// enable REST
_serviceClient.getOptions().setProperty(Constants.Configuration.ENABLE_REST,Constants.VALUE_TRUE);
```

Again if a comment the last line of code, session management is re-enabled.

Is that a bug or am I missing something?

I am using:

- Axis2 1.5.4
- Tomcat 7.0.8

Answer (score 1):

Session management for RESTful webservices works at the transport level only as opposed to  soap-based web services.

Thus, in order to enable session management for RESTful websevices, the following should be done.

In the **Client stub** code use the same code as above except that line about engaging addressing module should be commented or removed as REST does not support WS-addressing)

```
// enable session management 
_serviceClient.getOptions().setManageSession(true); 

// enable REST
_serviceClient.getOptions().setProperty(Constants.Configuration.ENABLE_REST,Constants.VALUE_TRUE);
```

**in services.xml** the web service desciption file 
add '**transportsession**' in the scope parameter

```
<service name="MyService" scope="transportsession"
    class="myPackage.service.MyServiceClass">
```

Don't forget to redeploy the web service.

That's it!